# Spring @Controller Not Returning View as Expected

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to return a view under my `/WEB-INF/jsp/` folder named person.jsp on click of of an anchor tag. My view resolver handles all views under this folder.  Here's my tag:

```
<a class="add" href="#">Click</a>
```

My AJAX GET Request:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(e) {
     request = /person/ + personID
     //success, failure, etc.
}
```

And here's my `@Controller`

```
@Controller 
public class RCITTFormController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPerson(@PathVariable String id){
        return "person";    
    }
}
```

However my persons.jsp is only returned in the HTTP Response (it's behaving as if I'd set my class as a `@RestController`). I've tried the "redirect:/person", returned a `ModelAndView` instance with `person` passed as the view, but to no avail. Is my problem something simpler, like the anchor tag itself? Could include more details if needed.

Thanks much

Comment: Am i correct to assume that you are trying to use AJAX to redirect to person.jsp?

Comment: Based on the code i see all it will do currently is stay on the parent page and return the view as a ajax response, is this what is currently happening?

Comment: Yes that's right; I realize now making an AJAX request and wanting a page redirect are contradictory.

Comment: Added a answer for you if what you are trying to do is go to a page using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution to this is as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(e) {
     request = /person/ + personID
     window.location.href = request;
}
```

That will direct you to the page you are after.

window.location.href will force your site to go to page you are after, but then you don't need ajax for this. Just use your standard anchor href.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return a ModelAndView like return new ModelAndView("person"). This if your JSP really is named as person.